# Does Mozilla have a feed that publishes just the Firefox release numbers?

Tags: firefox, feed, version

We have an in-house Firefox add-on at work, and I'd like to be notified of new Firefox releases so I can test our add-on right away.

I don't use Firefox as my primary browser.  I'm also on Ubuntu and use the Firefox from Ubuntu, so even if I did have it as my primary browser, it takes some time before I get the latest Firefox version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mozilla.announce group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mozilla.announce) is the simplest way find out about the the latest releases from Mozilla. Firefox, Thunderbird, Seamonkey, and other products are included in this stream so you will need to filter it.

The [Mozilla Firefox future release blog](http://blog.mozilla.com/futurereleases/) is the easiest place to keep informed on the latest Aurora, Beta, and Release versions of Firefox.

The [Release Tracking wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Features/Release_Tracking) will give you an idea when to expect the next release.

You can also sign up for the [Mozilla Firefox newsletter](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/#newsletter-signup).

Comment: I subscribed to the newsletter with my work e-mail address, so I don't have to check actively (as in the case of RSS feeds).

Comment: Stable & ESR: [RSS feed of the announce group](https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/mozilla.announce/msgs/rss_v2_0.xml?num=50), Beta & Nightly: [mozilla-central tags Atom feed](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/atom-tags)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is RSS subscription of this hyperlink. However, it gives updates from Thunderbird also but it will serve your purpose.

[Mozilla Developer News](https://developer.mozilla.org/devnews/)

Comment: Thanks!  But I subscribed to the newsletter with my work e-mail instead, so I don't have to check my feed reader for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if nothing else helps, you can always crawl -

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html";

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

version = soup.find('tr', {'id': 'en-US'}).find('td', {'class': 'curVersion'}).text
print version # Put a mail command here
```

Run the above code as cron every hour. Should work.